# How to get these data from Outlook programmatically, preferably via GRAPH?

Tags: outlook-restapi

please have a look at [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook-blog/microsoft-outlook-your-personal-organizer-helps-you-be-more/ba-p/3646388).
How to get data in the green rectangle programmatically, preferably via GRAPH?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Nobody knows that?